# Is it possible to get the the <div> HTML code with styles instead of classes in a String with Ionic Angular / Typescript to generate a mail html code?

Tags: angular, ionic4

Is it possible to get the `<div>` `HTML` code with styles instead of classes in a String with `Ionic Angular/Typescript` to generate a mail `HTML` code?

I want to get the InnerHTML (or equivalent), convert all class="" to style="" with their style equivalent and get it on a string to generate a email code. *The html code is generated dynamically.*

It is possible? How?